# Xamarin Android menu/submenu items - best practice

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, xamarin, submenu

I have an an Android app that requires that i give the user options to turn on or off certain brand names within specific categories.

So for example, I need to display categories such as Fashion, Music, Film etc (about 10-15 categories in total). Then the user needs to be able to click on a category and be presented with specific brands relating to that category which they can turn on and off, using perhaps a radio button or switch, depending on if they like that brand or not.

Can anybody advise as to a good way to display this kind of layout and what controls / layout to use. I'm currently thinking of using a grid layout for the categories, then submenu items or popup menu for the brands, but i'm not sure if they is a better way to go.

Also, i may need to include the brands actual logo so i need to allow for that to be possible in whatever view control i choose.

Answer (score 0):

I think a great way to show that kind of thing would be using a Card View.
Xamarin has an example on how to use it available here: http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/CardViewSample/

To use it you must add the nuget package for it to your project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView/